# insert unknown command to execvp()

Tags: c, shell, errno, execvp

hi
if i'm passing an unknown command to execvp i'm getting this error in the errno :
"no such file or directory"
when i should get this error:
"command not found"

how can i get the second error?

Answer (score 1):

Because "command not found" does not correspond to a standard error code (see e.g. http://linux.die.net/man/3/errno).

Answer (score 1):

There is no "command not found" error that can be returned from execvp. The closest is ENOENT, which means that the file specified (or its interpreter, or a required dynamic library) was not found.

If you want, your program could print out "command not found" rather than the text returned by strerror.